# How to use matplotlib FuncAnimation to animate a heatmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, heatmap

I'm trying to read through the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) for `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` to animate a heatmap.

I don't get any errors when I run the code below, and a heatmap plot does appear, but it doesn't seem animated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib


# generate random noise for the heatmap
rnd_data = np.random.normal(0, 1, (500, 100, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))

def my_func(i):
    sns.heatmap(rnd_data[i])

anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=my_func, frames=200, interval=500, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

The result of this code seems to be a single frame of `rnd_data`, namely the first array `rnd_data[0]`. I tried changing the number of `frames` and `interval` to larger numbers as I thought it was animating too fast for me to see, but this doesn't seem to have worked.

Am I doing something wrong here? I think I should be able to see the pixels of the plot change and move around like white noise when I plot the heatmap for such a dataset, but it isn't working. How can I animate the heatmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run correctly the animation, you have to use:

```
sns.heatmap(rnd_data[..., i])
```

so that you specify that the heatmap changes over time along the third axis.
The full code is below, I changed something in order to add correctly the colorbar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# generate random noise for the heatmap
rnd_data = np.random.normal(0, 1, (500, 100, 100))

def my_func(i):
    ax.cla()
    sns.heatmap(rnd_data[i, ...],
                ax = ax,
                cbar = True,
                cbar_ax = cbar_ax,
                vmin = rnd_data.min(),
                vmax = rnd_data.max())

grid_kws = {'width_ratios': (0.9, 0.05), 'wspace': 0.2}
fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(1, 2, gridspec_kw = grid_kws, figsize = (12, 8))
anim = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = my_func, frames = 200, interval = 50, blit = False)

plt.show()
```

which gives me this animation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This doesn't seem to work for me though - it plots, but not animated. Also, I actually want to change the heatmap along the first axis in time (that is 500 in length) so that the heatmap is a square 100x100, sorry if that wasn't clear in the question

Comment: I updated my answer in order to change the shape of the heatmap: now the `i` (which increases by 1 frame-by-frame) it flows along the first axis (which is 500 element long) and the heatmap is 100x100. I do not know why it does not animate in your case, have you copy and paste the whole code above? Are you using an IDE (like PyCharm) or Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I think my issue I am using jupyter notebooks. Because your code works fine in a python script, but does not animate in a jupyter notebook.. I wonder why that is. Thanks again!

Comment: To run an animation in Jupyter Notebook, read this [guide](http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-notebooks/).