# gettting a colorbar programmatically from an axis object

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

Consider the following code in which data is being plotted within a loop. In order to not plot multiple colorbars, I remove them before plotting new ones. However, I am tracking these colorbars manually. Is there a way to get a reference to them using, say, something like `ax[0].get_colorbar`. That would make my code a lot simpler.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# How to get a colorbar from an axis?

nrows = 1
ncols = 2
nstep = 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows,ncols=ncols)

cb0 = None
cb1 = None

for istep in range(nstep):
    data = np.random.random(size=(5,5))
    imu0 = ax[0].pcolormesh(data)
    imu1 = ax[1].pcolormesh(data)
    
    # this code is for removing previously drawn colorbars
    # I would like to get a reference to the colorbar cb0 from ax0 
    # and then remove it. 
    # I do not want to keep track of the colorbars manually 
    
    if cb0 is not None:
        cb0.remove()
    if cb1 is not None:
        cb1.remove()
    cb0 = plt.colorbar(imu0,ax=ax[0])
    cb1 = plt.colorbar(imu1,ax=ax[1])
```

Comment: Is the purpose of the color bar only on certain subplots? I don't understand the end goal.

Comment: @r-beginners I'm trying to make an animation saving png files with a loop. If I do not remove colorbars manually usning `cb.remove()` multiple colorbars get added to the axes. To keep track of the colorbars manually, the way I've done it in the code I posted, is not elegant. I'd much rather get colorbars using something like `cb=ax.get_colorbar` and then `cb.remove()` it.

Comment: If you don't want to add a color bar, you don't need cbn=plt.colorbar(imux,ax=ax[n]), though. Am I not understanding you well enough?

Comment: An example of a single heatmap animator station would be helpful for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411273/how-to-use-matplotlib-funcanimation-to-animate-a-heatmap).

Comment: @r-beginners I want a colorbar. I definitely want a colorbar for every subplot. However, if I do not remove it manually, a new colorbar is added to the figures. To see what I mean, run the code I posted with the `if` blocks commented out. I'm just interested in getting the colorbar object from the axis object (any other object such as fig) would work as well.

Comment: You already answered your own question, but why do you need 5 loops? `nstep=1` is the same as nstep=1, right?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do what I want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# How to get a colorbar from an axis?

nrows = 1
ncols = 2
nstep = 10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows,ncols=ncols)

cb0 = None
cb1 = None

for istep in range(nstep):
    data = np.random.random(size=(5,5))+istep
    imu0 = ax[0].pcolormesh(data)
    imu1 = ax[1].pcolormesh(data)

    if ax[0].collections[0].colorbar is None:
        cb0 = plt.colorbar(imu0,ax=ax[0])
    else:
        ax[0].collections[0].colorbar.update_normal(imu0)
        
    if ax[1].collections[0].colorbar is None:
        cb1 = plt.colorbar(imu1,ax=ax[1])
    else:
        ax[1].collections[0].colorbar.update_normal(imu1)
```